# How do I remove duplicates from a preg_match_all generated array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, preg-match-all

How do I remove duplicates from a preg_match_all generated array?

### Current array

```
Array
    (
    Array
        (
            'font-family: "Comic Sans";',
            'font-weight: bold;',
            'font-weight: normal;',
            'font-family: "Comic Sans";',
            'font-weight: normal;'
        )

    Array
        (
            'font-family',
            'font-weight',
            'font-weight',
            'font-family',
            'font-weight'
        )

    Array
        (
            '"Comic Sans"',
            'bold',
            'normal',
            '"Comic Sans"',
            'normal'
        )
    )
```

As you can see there are several duplicate values. The new array without the duplicate values should look like this.

### New array

```
Array
    (
    Array
        (
            font-family: "Comic Sans",
            font-weight: bold,
            font-weight: normal,
        )

    Array
        (
            font-family,
            font-weight,
            font-weight
        )

    Array
        (
            "Comic Sans",
            bold,
            normal
        )
    )
```

I know I could do this with an foreach but I`m sure there is a much prettier way to accomplish this result. What do I overlook?

Comment: You can use [`array_unique`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) on the inner arrays.

Comment: `array_unique()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it via:

```
//$rgData comes from preg_match_all
$rgResult = array_map('array_unique', $rgData);
```

Comment: `array_map` and `array_unique` better according to preg_match_all +1

Answer (score 1):

try to just use array_unique function

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

```
 $input = array(4, "4", "3", 4, 3, "3");
 $result = array_unique($input);
 var_dump($result);
```

output will be

```
 array(2) {
   [0] => int(4)
   [2] => string(1) "3"
 }
```

Comment: Not gonna work with only `array_unique` . It's multidimensional array. You should use with like `array_map` or loop in foreach

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<?php
foreach($array as $key=>$each) {
    $array[$key] = array_unique($each);
}
print_r($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
foreach($yourArray as $array){
  $array = array_unique($array);

}
```