# How to remove duplicates from multidimensional array after preg_match_all search?

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I'm trying to remove duplicates from a multidimensional array. I have read some related questions and have tried to adapt a super_unique method, but it's not working.

I'm generating results from a database by using preg_match_all to find a text pattern. The problem is that preg_match_all gives me a new entry in the array for every match, but I want only one. (I tried switching to preg_match, but I couldn't get that to work.) I read discussion of deduplication here and, from that, I tried the following code, but it's still preserving the duplicated.

```
$query = "SELECT shortword,word,essay,definitions FROM lexicon;";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);

$results = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $newtext=   $row["essay"]." ".$row["definitions"];
    if (preg_match_all("/(\<i\>U\<\/i\>|U) $episodenav\D/", $newtext, $matches)) {
        foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
            $match = ltrim(strip_tags($match), "U ");
            // array pseudo key is the float value of $match
            // add '_key' member for usort()
            $row['_key'] = floatval($match);
            $results[] = $row;
        }
    }
}

function super_unique($results) {
  $result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $results)));

  foreach ($result as $key => $value)
  {
    if ( is_array($value) )
    {
      $result[$key] = super_unique($value);
    }
  }

  return $result;
}
```

I wanted to the super_unique to get rid of all the duplicates (entries that have the same value of "shortword" from the database, for instance), but when I run this, it gives the same results as if the super_unique bit is not there.

Including the real data would be a little overwhelming, but I'll try to simulate it. Say $episodenav happens to be 12, and one row of the database looks like

shortword = "pride"
word = "pride and prejudice"
essay = "This is an essay about Pride and Prejudice (U 12), which has citations in a format that will be picked up by the preg_match_all twice (U 12)."
definitions = "A bunch of definitions that could also have citations matching the preg_match_all search (U 12)."

So after the preg_match_all search, my array will have three entries for shortword="pride", and I want to make a list that has an entry based on each shortword. It ends up at this step:

```
// ... then display stuff in order
foreach($results as $row) {
    $row['_key'] = number_format((float)$row['_key'], 0, '', '');    echo '<p class="textmark_result">' . (string)$row['_key'] . ' (episode as whole)';
    echo '  <a href="../Pivot/lexiconentry.php?shortword=' 
. $row["shortword"] . '">' . $row["word"] . '</a>';
    echo "</p>\n";
```

With the current code, I get three entries for "pride", but I want only one.

Comment: It would help to show show sample data along with what you are trying to match.

Comment: Yes, show original data and expected result.

Comment: Thanks. I've added more information at the end that, I hope, simulates how the data works well enough to explain the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove duplicates from a preg\_match\_all generated array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867142/how-do-i-remove-duplicates-from-a-preg-match-all-generated-array)